# Помогите найти музыку из kindome come deliverence!

Tags: музыка

Понравилась мне музыка во время боя в вышеперечисленной игре. Никак не могу найти ее название. Может, кто подскажет?

Comment: Пробовал... Эх. Там я все переслушал и ничего нету

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А поиск имя_игры soundtrack не пробовали?

Comment: Регулярное выражение лучше :)

Comment: Конечно, Еще не забыть правильно указать все параметры, и помнить, что bash круче cmd

Comment: Elastic лучше же...

Comment: Голосуем, закрываем товарища

Comment: Давайте только не будем меряться.... Инициатор спрашивал о другом

Comment: Не надо пока закрывать: неужели мы сами над собой не можем посмеяться? ;-)